# Trying to configure WebGL

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

I am trying to initialize my graphics library to draw a simple triangle to my web browser. However, the `gl` object that I am creating does not seem to be global and it is still set to undefined even though I initialized it. Where am I going wrong?

```js
var gl;
var points;

window.onload = function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);

    if (!gl) {
        alert("WebGL is not available");
    }
}
//three vertices
    var vertices = [vec2(-1, -1), vec2(0, -1), vec2(1, -1)];

//configure WebGL
    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

//load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    var program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
    gl.userProgram(program);

//load the data into the GPU
    var bufferID = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

//Associate out shader variables with our data buffer
    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, fl.FLOAT, flase, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
    render();

function render()
{
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec4 vPosition;
        void main(){
            gl_Position = vPosition;
         }
    </script>
    <script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;
        void main(){
            gl_FragColor = vec4 ( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../test1/webgl-utils.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../test1/initShaders.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../test1/MV.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../test1/triangle.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512" height="512">
    Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put the "//three vertices" until "//Associate out shader variables with our data buffer" code inside the init method. This code is now executed before init. Try to debug your code to understand the program flow.

Comment: do not use `window.onload`. Just put your script below your body's closing tag. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/jz5z7h4r/   You'll find this advice in pretty much all major internet companies's coding guidelines. There is no reason to use `window.onload`. That practices is left over from bad examples from 15 years ago and just keeps getting copy and pasted over and over. The only reason to use `window.onload` is because you put your script at the top. Things get executed in order top to bottom so your HTML below your script doesn't yet exist. Move the script ot the bottom problem solved

Comment: either that or use the `defer` tag. In either case, no reason to use `window.onload`. `window.onload` is also problematic because some old 3rdparty scripts might also try to set it and either you'll override them or they'll override you. If you really need to execute on load then you should really be using `window.addEventListener('load', yourFunction)` since that way more than one script can execute on load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a several issue in your code.

Move all the initilizations to the function `onload`. Without that, the initialization would be done before the webgl context is initialized

```
window.onload = function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);

    if (!gl) {
        alert("WebGL is not available");
    }
// } <----------------- remove this

//three vertices

   .....
   render();
} // <----------------- add this
```

---

Your vertex coordinates form a straight line, because all the Y coordinates are -1. You want see any triangle:

```
var vertices = [vec2(-1, -1), vec2(0, -1), vec2(1, -1)];
```

Change it to

```
var vertices = [vec2(-1, -1), vec2(0, 1), vec2(1, -1)];
```

---

Ther are some typos in your code.

`userProgram` -> `useProgram`

`bufferId` -> `bufferID`

`fl.FLOAT, flase` -> `gl.FLOAT, false`

---

See the code snippet:

```js
var gl;
var points;

window.onload = function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);

    if (!gl) {
        alert("WebGL is not available");
    }

//three vertices
    var vertices = [-1, -1, 0, 1, 1, -1];

//configure WebGL
    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

//load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    var program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
    gl.useProgram(program); // userProgram -> useProgram

//load the data into the GPU
    var bufferID = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferID); // bufferId -> bufferID
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

//Associate out shader variables with our data buffer
    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0); // fl -> gl, flase -> flase
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
    render();
}

function render()
{
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

var WebGLUtils = {
    setupWebGL: function(canvas) {
        return canvas.getContext("webgl");
    }
};

function flatten(a) {
    return new Float32Array( a )
}

function initShaders(gl, vs, fs) {
    prog = ShaderProgram.Create( 
      [ { source : vs, stage : gl.VERTEX_SHADER },
        { source : fs, stage : gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER }
      ] );
      if ( prog == 0 )
        alert("invalid shader");
    return prog;
} 

var ShaderProgram = {};
ShaderProgram.Create = function( shaderList ) {
    var shaderObjs = [];
    for ( var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderList.length; ++ i_sh ) {
        var shderObj = this.CompileShader( shaderList[i_sh].source, shaderList[i_sh].stage );
        if ( shderObj == 0 )
            return 0;
        shaderObjs.push( shderObj );
    }
    var progObj = this.LinkProgram( shaderObjs )
    if ( progObj != 0 ) {
        progObj.attribIndex = {};
        var noOfAttributes = gl.getProgramParameter( progObj, gl.ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES );
        for ( var i_n = 0; i_n < noOfAttributes; ++ i_n ) {
            var name = gl.getActiveAttrib( progObj, i_n ).name;
            progObj.attribIndex[name] = gl.getAttribLocation( progObj, name );
        }
        progObj.unifomLocation = {};
        var noOfUniforms = gl.getProgramParameter( progObj, gl.ACTIVE_UNIFORMS );
        for ( var i_n = 0; i_n < noOfUniforms; ++ i_n ) {
            var name = gl.getActiveUniform( progObj, i_n ).name;
            progObj.unifomLocation[name] = gl.getUniformLocation( progObj, name );
        }
    }
    return progObj;
}
ShaderProgram.AttributeIndex = function( progObj, name ) { return progObj.attribIndex[name]; } 
ShaderProgram.UniformLocation = function( progObj, name ) { return progObj.unifomLocation[name]; } 
ShaderProgram.Use = function( progObj ) { gl.useProgram( progObj ); } 
ShaderProgram.SetUniformI1  = function( progObj, name, val ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform1i( progObj.unifomLocation[name], val ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformF1  = function( progObj, name, val ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform1f( progObj.unifomLocation[name], val ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformF2  = function( progObj, name, arr ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform2fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], arr ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformF3  = function( progObj, name, arr ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform3fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], arr ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformF4  = function( progObj, name, arr ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform4fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], arr ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformM33 = function( progObj, name, mat ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniformMatrix3fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], false, mat ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformM44 = function( progObj, name, mat ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniformMatrix4fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], false, mat ); }
ShaderProgram.CompileShader = function( source, shaderStage ) {
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(source);
    if (shaderScript) {
      source = "";
      var node = shaderScript.firstChild;
      while (node) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3) source += node.textContent;
        node = node.nextSibling;
      }
    }
    var shaderObj = gl.createShader( shaderStage );
    gl.shaderSource( shaderObj, source );
    gl.compileShader( shaderObj );
    var status = gl.getShaderParameter( shaderObj, gl.COMPILE_STATUS );
    if ( !status ) alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shaderObj));
    return status ? shaderObj : 0;
} 
ShaderProgram.LinkProgram = function( shaderObjs ) {
    var prog = gl.createProgram();
    for ( var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderObjs.length; ++ i_sh )
        gl.attachShader( prog, shaderObjs[i_sh] );
    gl.linkProgram( prog );
    status = gl.getProgramParameter( prog, gl.LINK_STATUS );
    if ( !status ) alert("Could not initialise shaders");
    gl.useProgram( null );
    return status ? prog : 0;
}
```

```html
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec4 vPosition;
    void main(){
        gl_Position = vPosition;
     }
</script>
<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;
    void main(){
        gl_FragColor = vec4 ( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    }
</script>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512" height="512">
      Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
 </canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you! Expanding the initialization function did the trick, as well as correcting my many typos. Thanks for the headache relief!